# Crear un join con los resultados de procedimientos almacenados

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola tengo dos querys para que me devuelva el resultado de dos procedimientos almacenados

```
DECLARE @return_value int EXEC  @return_value = [dbo].[SP_TABLE_PRODUCTOS_ALMACEN] SELECT   'Return Value' = @return_value 

DECLARE @return_value1 int EXEC @return_value1 = [dbo].[SP_TABLE_CLIENTES] SELECT   'Return Value' = @return_value1
```

Con los resultados debo crear un inner join. Alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 1):

Si los procedures devuelven un solo result set, podrías crear variables de tipo tabla con la estructura del set devuelto por el procedure, y luego trabajar con esas variables para hacer el join, por ej:

DECLARE @Tabla TABLE (int numero, ...)

INSERT INTO @Tabla
EXEC [dbo].[SP_TABLE_PRODUCTOS_ALMACEN]